# Word to describe a slice of multi-dimensional space

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

*Ported from English Language & Usage*

I'm in the market for a mathematical (or otherwise) **term to describe a slice of a hypercube**.

*Tensor* is out of the running as that's the name of the object I am slicing.

The second I could use a hand with is a term to describe an index (or *access point*) that spans more than a single point in each dimension.

Though about using *Ranged Index* as a collection of *Ranged Dimension*, but I'm **really** hoping there's a more concise and explicit alternative.

For example:

- **Regular index** `[1, 2, 1]` would access index 1 in dimension-one, index 2 in dimension-2 and index 1 in dimension-3
- **Spanning Index (or whatever)** `[3->4, 1, 4->9]` would access all elements between indices 3 and 4 of dimension-1, index 1 of dimension-2, etc...

**More about *Index*:**
It's programming terminology for a address to a section of data. I have a Tensor: a finite set of data points collected into a hypercube with each datapoint being accessible by a unique "address" using its position along each axis of the hypercube.

For a matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}5 & 3\\2 & 9\end{bmatrix}$

The value at:

- matrix[0,0] is 5
- matrix[1,0] is 2
- matrix[0,1] is 3
- matrix[1,1] is 9

with [0,0],[1,0],... being indices. For a cube of data one would access using [a,b,c]. If one wanted to specify a range of dimensions (i.e. cut a matrix out of a cube) They could index [0, 1->4, 2->5] extracting a 4x4 matrix from the cube.

Anyways, if indexing is out of scope and/or my explanation lacks clarity, simply ignore it.

Comment: What do you mean by "access" and "index"? This doesn't mean anything for a hypercube... on the other hand, you mention a *tensor* and the only thing that fits here is if you mean it as a multi-dimensional table — note that this is a somewhat uncommon use of the term in mathematics, although it may be more usual in physics. Now... the term *section* seems to be the most fitting here, but note that it only refers to the intersection of a geometric object with a hyperplane (for example, think of a cube and a plane). Ultimately, it all boils down to: what do you need this term for?

Comment: Instead of "slice", you could use "cross-section". Not sure about the index, but you might want to look at the [Schläfli symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol).

Comment: @A.P. Section is one that escaped me. Yes, I suppose indexing would be out of the scope of this Exchange. I've updated my post with more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use the term "hypercube" here, because that's [not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) what you're talking about. Instead, you are talking about a *multi-dimensional table*, which you could think of as the vertex set of a refinement of the [1-dimensional skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) of a hypercube.

It is important to understand *what you need this term for*, though. For example, are you writing an article? If so and your target are computer scientists, then *slice* is actually the best term, because in various programming languages used in the scientific community (e.g. Python or MATLAB) it refers exactly to what you call "spanning index" in your question. On the other hand, if your target are mathematicians then you could choose almost anything, by you should *define* the terms you use. Both *slice* and "*partial section*" would be nice choices — note that I coined the second term, but a mathematician shouldn't have trouble understanding what you mean by it (but don't rely on this).

By the way, If you're talking to CS people *index* is a fine term, but if you're talking to mathematicians then you should use either *entry* if you're talking about a table, *vertex* if you're talking about a graph, or *point* if you're talking about a geometrical object. Confusingly enough, the objects that form what you call an index, e.g. $1$, $2$, and $1$ in $[1,2,1]$, are called *indices* in the first case and *coordinates* in the other two cases.

Answer (score 2):

In math, a tuple used to index a multi-dimensional array is often called a [*multi-index*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation). In programming, an index that spans a range of values is often called a [*slice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) or a *slice index*. I would therefore suggest a term like ***multi-slice*** or ***slice multi-index***.

---

By the way, you're using the words "tensor" and "hypercube" in a way that could be confusing to many mathematicians.

In typical mathematical parlance, just as a matrix is a way of representing a linear map, a multi-dimensional array is a way of representing a tensor. You're dealing with multi-dimensional arrays, rather than the tensors they represent.

Although a matrix might be described informally as a square of numbers, it could be confusing to refer to a matrix as a square. Referring to a multi-dimensional array as a hypercube is liable to cause similar confusion.